# 404 error using Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat

I have this kind of error when I try to register:

This is my :

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Hotelbooking</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hotelbooking</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Hotelbooking</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hotelbooking</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hotelbooking</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>Login</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <display-name>Logout</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Logout</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Logout</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <display-name>Registration</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>hotel.Registration</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/registration</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /HotelReservation/Registration
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

[myProject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1u0N.png)

Comment: Have you written a controller for `HotelReservation`? What mvc are you using? Is it annotation based or xml? Have you configured the mvc to point to the relevant controller?

Comment: You don't seem to have a url-pattern for `/HotelReservation/Registration`, assuming `HotelReservation` is your context-root and `Registration` with a capital `R` is the url you're trying to access

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes and I write my web.xml file for this no?

Comment: Yes, but I see `<url-pattern>/registration</url-pattern>` which to obtain what you want should be `<url-pattern>/Registration</url-pattern>`, with a capital `R`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca now I try!

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You are right man! I'm so stupid

Comment: Don't worry :) But I'll have to vote to close this question as "typo", don't take it the wrong way :)